# Find connections on same row SQL through other column

Tags: mysql

I have some problem finding a solutions for this in MySQL. I would like to create a query which can count the number of time two distinct values in a row have been mentioned with the same value in a different column.

More specifically I would like to find the number of times two inventors have worked together on the same patent. I have created the output manually in excel but don't have a solution for it in SQL code.

The table I have is the one below:

```
Patent      Inventor
04412478    D0456998-2
04926296    D0456998-2
05597593    D0456998-1
06267663    07225494-3
06299015    07225494-3
06299015    D0456998-1
06301919    07225494-3
06301919    D0456998-1
06311837    D0456998-1
06311837    D0456998-2
06360395    07225494-3
06360395    D0456998-1
06360395    D0456998-2
06371294    07225494-3
06371294    D0456998-1
06371294    D0456998-2
06546585    D0456998-1
06546585    D0456998-2
06663482    07225494-3
06988292    06245813-3
06988292    06877638-0
D0437469    07225494-3
D0465088    07225494-3
D0465088    D0456998-1
D0465088    D0456998-2
```

This would then be the output of the query:

```
Inventor 1  Inventor 2  Collaborations
06245813-3  06877638-0  1
07225494-3  D0456998-1  5
07225494-3  D0456998-2  3
D0456998-1  D0456998-2  5
```

How would I tackle this problem? Would greatly appreciate any suggestions or help!

Comment: You would join the table to itself. Still struggling? See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry almost there. I've come this far now: https://pastebin.com/PpkgBqL3 I just need to filter out the duplicate over column 1 and 2. Any ideas here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT x.inventor inventor1
     , y.inventor inventor2
     , COUNT(*) total
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.patent = x.patent 
   AND y.inventor < x.inventor 
 GROUP
    BY x.inventor
     , y.inventor;
```

Comment: Ah perfect! It was that `<` sign I was missing. Thanks for the help!

Comment: ...in addition to the rest of the query!